# how to show document From Server Side To client Side using DWR

Tags: jquery, html, file-transfer, dwr

Hi i want to view a document which i receive from server side that is File Transfer object from #DWR

I want to  view this document ,There can be any type of Documents .How to Do this Can anyone help?I'm new to this

I tried this one [a link] (http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/394-Google-Docs-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html)!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12070073/1546513  Are you familiar with dwr? I think that there is a few errors in that post, but you can get a basic idea...

Comment: @ElyeM . Thank you for your reply but i dont want the document ie openIndownload but i have pdfobject Which i will show the preview of the PDF file any idea on how to do that?